# What is the time granularity in Android?

Tags: java, android, time, clock

I know Windows has clock time granularity in tens of milliseconds.

- What time granularity does Android OS use?
- What granularity is provided in `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `System.nanoTime()`?
- Do these methods in Android use the same HW time source?

Comment: For current time millis, try writing a simple test using Thread.sleep(1) and then writing the values to the console. For nanoTime(), you can write a tight loop and output the value each time it changes. Stop when the value changes 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean by granularity:

For the first/third point:
It depends on 2 factors, Hardware (so cpu clock, bus and so on) and on the System workload (it can cause delays) so you can:

- calculate the granularity by checking the time difference between 2 outputs
- check if the android version you're using provides a method to determine the granularity, but usually it depends on some driver at a level lower than the VM one

For the second point:

- "System.currentTimeMillis()" return the time in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 UTC.
- "System.nanoTime()" returns the current value of the running Java Virtual Machine's high-resolution time source, in nanoseconds.

(Information source [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()))

But they depend on the VM used by the Android system.